# ffmpeg option, subchunk1size = 16

Tags: ffmpeg, pcm

I have a wav file. 
How can I use ffmpeg with specific options to convert it to a wave file with subchunk1size = 16.

Comment: But isn't it always 16 by default? I thought that was the standard for PCM.

Comment: Yes, usually subchunk1size = 16. However, I have some wav file that has subchunk1size = 18. Now I want to convert it to the wav file that has subchunk1size = 16.

Comment: Then the wFormatTag will  not be `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM`. Maybe just converting to PCM will do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I tried `sox`, this command should do the trick:

```
sox original_18subchunkFile.wav -r16000 -esigned-integer -b16 -c1 new_16subchunkFile.wav
```